# How to select two or more ranges from excel sheet with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Well, I have a doubt, i want to know how to select multiple information from Excel to insert in SQL Server Database.

But i have a problem, i want to insert only the selected information like this image.

[image: Example of information]

I want to select the column (A,D,E), not the C and D column, why I don't select all ? , because in the excel file the B,C,D, and E columns has the same column name, and i only want to insert the D and E column,

I had this SQL Query, but it doesn't work, it don't select me the first column (PART NUMBER), but it select correctly the D and E Column.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 8.0; Database=\\s1\files\file.xlsx;HDR=YES; IMEX=1', 
    'SELECT [PARTNUMBER] [COL1], [COL2]  FROM [EMB$D:E], [EMB$A:A] WHERE [PART NUMBER] IS NOT NULL');
```

Comment: `'SELECT [PARTNUMBER] [COL1], [COL2]  FROM [EMB$D:E], [EMB$A:A] WHERE [PART NUMBER] IS NOT NULL');` You're missing a comma after [PARTNUMBER], and [PART NUMBER] / [PARTNUMBER] isn't consistent - which is it? Try `'SELECT [PARTNUMBER], [COL1], [COL2]  FROM [EMB$D:E], [EMB$A:A] WHERE [PARTNUMBER] IS NOT NULL');`

Comment: Yes, but i execute the query like: 'SELECT [PARTNUMBER], [COL1], [COL2] FROM [EMB$D:E], [EMB$A:A] WHERE [PARTNUMBER] IS NOT NULL'); , and It not show me all the information that i want, the query doesn't take both ranges...